# How to call a macro from another module but run in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that does some calculations, which is located in a module on "Optimum" sheet (I do not want the user to access this sheet, btw). I have 5 other sheets let's say called "p1" "p2" "p3" "p4" "p5" where the user is able to input data.

Starting with "p1". User inputs the data and the data copies over to "Optimum" Sheet and the calculations are done.

The problem is that the table of results and calculations of "Optimum" are being show in "p1" instead of not showing anything at all.

I'm trying Application.Run and Call but I do understand this just calls a macro to the active worksheet you are in, hence my problem.

```
Sub Macroforp1()

Sheets("p1").Range("TablePV1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Optimum").Range("TableOptimum")
'
'
Call Optimum_module.TestCalc
'
End Sub
```

I expect the code to just grab the input on whichever sheet I'm in, run the calculations on "Optimum" and that's it. (Later I will grab a certain row of results to paste in the sheets I mentioned).

Comment: just googled "vba excel How to call a macro from another module but run in another sheet" and the [first not video result](https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-run-a-macro-from-another-workbook/) was _"To run a macro contained in another workbook, use the Application.Run command as follows:"_ `Application.Run "'Another Workbook.xlsm'!NameOfMacro"`

Comment: You might also need/want to add a parameter to that macro that accepts a Worksheet object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did read through the link you provided before, but it hadn't worked/applied to what I'm trying to do.
I'm in the same workbook, so I don't need to call another xlsm. What I'm trying to do is grabbing data from a sheet and running through calculations in another. The thing is that the calculations sheet creates some tables and formulas that should only appear in that sheet and not in the one I have the data being grabbed from (which is what is happening)